# unmarshall simple json data with golang

Tags: json, go

https://go.dev/play/p/L2IJp-ehA2S

The following program provides me the required output (ccc09e). But this is correct approach or this can be improved.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type People struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    empJson := `[{"name":"ccc09e"}]`
    var emp []People
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(empJson), &emp)
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%v", emp[0])
    s = s[1 : len(s)-1]
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

I got the required output https://go.dev/play/p/L2IJp-ehA2S  and I need improvement to the program.

Comment: "improvement" in what dimension? Speed? Memory? Maintainability?

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf` is great for debugging generic data structure, but please don't use it's output for application logic.

Comment: ok.I'll stop using Sprintf. @Volker I was looking for improvements to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the `Name` of the First element of `People` array in `s`

No need to do string manipulations. Just access it directly

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type People struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    empJson := `[{"name":"ccc09e"}]`
    var emp []People
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(empJson), &emp)
    s := emp[0].Name
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/O2hiGuSyM53